# MediaWiki on SubDirectory and SubDomain

Tags: apache, subdomain, mediawiki, subdirectory

I wish to setup a MediaWiki install on both `http://wiki.mysite.com/` and `http://mysite.com/wiki/`, I figure there's some kind of trick to it, I assume that with at least a little tinkering I can get this working...

I installed it in a directory which aliased to `http://mysite.com/wiki/`, then setup another Apache VirtualHost, but now when I navigate to `http://wiki.mysite.com/` I'm redirected to `http://wiki.mysite.com/wiki/Main_Page`, and get an internal server error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: More info, please. Post your current .htaccess, how the virtual hosts are routed and and where your MW files are situated. It's normal that MediaWiki redirects to what it thinks is its correct path, but that in itself shouldn't cause a 500 internal.

Answer (score 5):

I just moved my Wiki from `/var/www/html/` to `/var/www/html/wiki`.

I needed to modify `$wgScriptPath` in `LocalSettings.php` from `""` to `"/wiki";`

Then I needed to restart Apache: `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Now navigating my browser to `http://46.101.38.186/wiki` correctly displays the main wiki page.