# Mediawiki Subdirectory Installation

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mediawiki, subdirectory

> **Possible Duplicate:** [MediaWiki on SubDirectory and SubDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763909/mediawiki-on-subdirectory-and-subdomain) (However doesn't have an answer, nor any replies offering help)

Alright, I'm trying to configure MediaWiki to be installed to a sub-directory. I previously had it installed to a primary domain on http://www.example.com/ with a mod_rewrite using a Short URL of `/wiki/Main_Title`.

*As a note, I'm also on [HostGator](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/wiki/Page_title_--_PHP_as_a_CGI_module,_no_root_access) shared hosting which has [special rules](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/wiki/Page_title_--_PHP_as_a_CGI_module,_no_root_access) for short urls.*

My directory structure is as such:

- `/` `(site root; location of .htaccess)`
- `/wiki/` `(mediawiki root; location of LocalSettings.php)`

Here's what I tried,

**`.htaccess`:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\&(.*)$ $1\%26$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.+)$ ./wiki/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

**`/wiki/LocalSettings.php`:**

```
## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs please see:
## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
##
$wgScriptPath       = "/wiki";
$wgScriptExtension  = ".php";
$wgArticlePath      = "$wgScriptPath/$1";
```

However, I do not get anything. I simply get a `403/Forbidden` error; no `500 Internal Server Error`, just a 403 - **url http://www.example.com/**. It's as if there's nothing being done. I've banged my head against the wall trying to figure this out. Any help is appreciated.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Also, if more information is needed, please ask and I'll try my best to provide whatever information you *need*. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MediaWiki on SubDirectory and SubDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763909/mediawiki-on-subdirectory-and-subdomain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ticket to HostGator resolved the issue, albeit un-helpfully. I was hoping for a *single* `.htaccess` solution, rather than a double `.htaccess` redirect/rewrite. However, here's my solution.

**`/`:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/wiki/
```

---

**`/wiki/`:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\&(.*)$ $1\%26$2
```

<strike>You've lost me entirely on this one.  Any URI with a second parameter will loop indefinitely and generate a 500 status return.</strike>

If you read the Rewrite documentation:

> **What is matched?**
>
> ...If you wish to match against the ... query string, use a RewriteCond with the ... `%{QUERY_STRING}` variables

The & is normally part of the query parameter.  It can appear in the RewriteRule pattern in the case of malformed URI (e.g. `fred&q=1`).  By default, mod_rewrite will treat this as `fred?q=1`, but this converts it to the escaped %26 variant so this would be passed as a title `fred&q=1` to MW (which is an invalid MW title by the way).  I think that you should get rid of it or at least understand what you are trying to do here.

The last line should be

```
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.+) wiki/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

and keep the `RewriteBase` otherwise mod_rewrite can get confused.

This should work OK:-)

Comment: The purpose of that line was from Mediawiki's Wiki for ShortURL configuration on HostGator.

Comment: @Zack, It might be in a 2009 edit by Choshi, but it doesn't make it valid. See the MW talk page. It doesn't make sense because & is part of the QUERY_STRING and this is stripped out of the pattern by the engine.  You will never match \& in a RewriteRule.  I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track... if you're on a shared environment, then try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Comment to force base to be the subdir:
# RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\&(.*)$ $1\%26$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.+)$ ./wiki/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

---

### Two hints:

If you're not in a hosted environment (= if it's your own server and you can modify the virtual hosts, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: I'm on a shared hosting environment with cPanel and FTP access. Where do I access these logs? O.o

Comment: I went [here](http://www.bestdesigns.co.in/blog/create-apache-rewrite-log-file) and tried the `.htaccess` solution to enable the rewrite logs, but I got a 500 ISE :/

Comment: If you're on a shared hosting then you can't enable log, otherwise you'll get an 500. Could you try to install it locally, on your own PC, try to make a vhost and apply everything you need until it works? Otherwise it may be tough to find where exactly the error is...

Comment: Doesn't appear to work :(

A solution I thought of was to use two rewrites (one in each directory) where the root (`/`) rewrites to `/wiki/` and the one in `/wiki/` rewrites mediawiki. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: I also put a ticket into HG's support to see if they have any solutions. If I get anything from them, I'll post back here with the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried different solutions and what worked for me was changing .htaccess in mediawiki subfolder to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wikifolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```