# How to redirect all files/folders except index.php, to index.php?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I've set up a dummy website to test MediaWiki at https://wiki.rehman.website/

I want to redirect all direct external traffic to files and folders located after wiki.rehman.website/ to wiki.rehman.website/index.php. So for example:

These should redirect to wiki.rehman.website/index.php:

- wiki.rehman.website/extensions/
- wiki.rehman.website/docs/contenthandler.txt
- wiki.rehman.website/NonExistantFileOrFolder

But obviously these should not be redirected (to prevent circular redirects):

- wiki.rehman.website/
- wiki.rehman.website/index.php

How do I do that please?

What I'm trying to achieve here is to prevent anonymous users (i.e. non-MediaWiki logged in users) accessing any part of the web directory or files.

This is my first time setting up a website, and my first time installing a private instance of MediaWiki. If you spot any other loophole or issue, it would be most helpful if you could let me know.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a .htaccess file in your root folder to accomplish that.

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

See this other question for more information:
[How to Redirect All urls to a new domain in apache, except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629430/how-to-redirect-all-urls-to-a-new-domain-in-apache-except-one)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, both options seem to partially break the site. The redirecting works, but elements of the MediaWiki site seems to be blocked.

Maybe this also redirects MediaWiki's attempts access other parts of the web directory?

If you look at a common MediaWiki site like Wikipedia, accessing URLs such as https://en.wikipedia.org/docs or https://en.wikipedia.org/docs/contenthandler.txt doesn't work. 

If redirecting wouldn't work in my case, how do I do what Wikipedia does? Thank you for your help!

Comment: it seams like this answer might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50504756/68264 you should also disable directory listings on .htaccess with "Options -Indexes" or on your apache.config so no one can take a peak at all of your files.